# How can I display the company name and company logo in OpenCart

Tags: opencart

How to display the Store name along with the logo in the front end?

Actually, I want to display my company name along with the logo whatever I write in `system->settings->General (store name)`. If I update this, only the logo displays but not the storename.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to edit the code

File:
upload/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl

Locate:

```
<?php if ($logo) { ?>
<div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Replace:

```
<?php if ($logo) { ?>
<div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $this->config->get('config_name'); ?><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store name

```
<?php echo $this->config->get('config_name'); ?>
```

Logo

```
<?php echo HTTP_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_logo'); ?>
```

Comment: This outputs an error on footer.tpl Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in

Comment: If you're using 2.X that will be why. You can't access these in templates any more as of version 2.0

Comment: Is there a way to do this or a go around? Thanks for the reply; wonder why they moved it

Comment: Add `global $config;` before any calls to config, then use `$config->get` instead. That will work

Comment: Can you update the answer and give an example; is there a list of all calls we can do now in OpenCart 2.0 - the docs and forums have nothing - thanks for this + 1

Comment: The new version doesn't allow any `$this->` methods. So you need to assign them in the controller. To be honest, that's the way you should do it anyway, not this way. Just assign the value to `$data` in your controller with the value above for config name/logo

Comment: No but I want to be able to do a few of these calls in phtml files such as footer and product and information - I am building a template and I dont want to touch controller files as it is touching core files then. What would you suggest. Is there a hack I can bring the old 1.5 feature back

Comment: As I say - you can use `global $config` at the top of your template and then use `$config->get('value_here');` in place of the original items - but it's very hackish and not recommended. You would be best adding the values to controllers using VQMod so that your theme is still separate, but using a proper MVC structure. This is how most themes do this

Comment: Thank you for this. I guess if it does not work I will open another thread or look for another solution. Regarding the VQMod I think it is an embarrassment solution and I detest it. That is more hackish to me.